# need help on jenkins build script

Tags: git, github, jenkins

my build keeps on failing, in the configuration under build script i have:

```
if [ ! -d "./.git" ]; then
  git init
  git remote add origin git@github.com:miranetworks/rainbow_code
fi
git fetch -q origin
git reset -q --hard $JANKY_SHA1
if [ -f script/cibuild ]; then
  script/cibuild
else
  bundle install --path vendor/gems --binstubs
  bundle exec rake
fi
```

i am also building without parameters
the failed build log shows the following:

```
Started by user helloise smit
Building remotely on i-61a1df04 in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/rainbow_code
Checkout:rainbow_code / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/rainbow_code -        
 hudson.remoting.Channel@72bbffd:i-61a1df04
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 9f9d6f94c220a1ae079fded09c4d23d9c1b1801d (origin/HEAD, 
origin/master)
Checkout:rainbow_code / /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/rainbow_code -   
hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@142b716
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:miranetworks/rainbow_code.git
Commencing build of Revision 9f9d6f94c220a1ae079fded09c4d23d9c1b1801d (origin/master)
Checking out Revision 9f9d6f94c220a1ae079fded09c4d23d9c1b1801d (origin/master)
[rainbow_code] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1783123371374377301.sh
+ [ ! -d ./.git ]
+ git fetch -q origin
+ git reset -q --hard
+ [ -f script/cibuild ]
+ bundle install --path vendor/gems --binstubs
/tmp/hudson1783123371374377301.sh: 1: bundle: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

what does this all mean? 
anyone that can help please?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Hudson could not find the `bundle` command. It looks like it is not part of the path during hudson execution. Try supplying the full path in your script (you can find out where `bundle` is located with `which bundle`.

Comment: the script i pasted is run by jenkins, i did not write it. if it could not find the bundle command it is not installed and should i try and install manually rather? thanks

Comment: try installing it with `gem install bundler`

Comment: i keep on getting the following now:  $gem install bundler
WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 and
   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /home/helloises/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin in your PATH,
   gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  Error installing bundler:
 bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
i checked both dirs are executable and wheni do gem -v i get 1.3.5?? but i ran gem install rubygems-update?

Comment: looks like you don't have write permissions: use `sudo gem install bundler`

Comment: i followed this and it installed the bundler. will check if jenkins now build http://dradisframework.org/community/index.php?topic=382.0

Answer (score 1):

This is not a git problem but a bundler problem.

> bundle: not found

That means that the bundle commands does not exists in your path.

Maybe you need to install bundler on your platform:

```
$ gem install bundler
```

If gem is configured to install into user directory, you need to install bundler for the Jenkins user:

```
$ su jenkins
$ gem install bundler
```